# Best way to iterate over a vector of events SDL2

Tags: c++, vector, sdl-2

I have a event handler class that adds all events to a vector. This vector is cleared after each frame. However if it is cleared after each frame the events cannot be detected outside of the handle function of the event handler class. If I don't clear the vector at the end of each frame. The program becomes unresponsive. Although I can check that my for loop is reading the vector of events for a while until the vector becomes for to clogged up for the program to make sense of it.

My questions are:

Is the use of a for loop to iterate over the events a good way to check for these events? Or would it be more useful to use a while loop to check this vector for events much like you would using `while(SDL_PollEvents(&e))`?

Why would my program become unresponsive when I am checking the events within the vector when I am not clearing the vector?

How can I efficently check my vector `eventList` outside of the class. Where I could check for keydown events or similar using the vector and also clearing the vector after I have checked for the events without the program becoming unresponsive?

This is my main function where I am trying to read these events without the above mentioned problems.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    EventHandler handler;

      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(handler.render, 49, 49, 49, 255);
      SDL_RenderClear(handler.render);

      SDL_RenderPresent(handler.render);
      if(handler.eventList.size() >= 1){
        std::cout << "Detected an event: " << handler.eventList.size() << "\n";
      }
      for(std::vector<SDL_Event>::const_iterator i = handler.get().begin(); i != handler.get().end(); i++){
        if(i->type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
          if (i->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w){
            std::cout << "You pressed the W key\n";
          }
        }
      }
      handler.eventList.clear();
      handler.handle();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is where I want to be able to check the events thats in the `eventList`

```
  for(std::vector<SDL_Event>::const_iterator i = handler.get().begin(); i != handler.get().end(); i++){
    if(i->type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
      if (i->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w){
        std::cout << "You pressed the W key\n";
      }
    }
  }
```

This is a simplified version of my `eventHandler` class

```
class EventHandler {
public:
    
    bool quit;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* render;

    int width;
    int height;

    std::vector<SDL_Event> eventList;


    EventHandler()
    {
        //Iniliaze SDL
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        }
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Fallen Planets", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1024, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        if (window == NULL){
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
            SDL_Quit();
            quit = true;
        }
        render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (render == NULL){
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
            SDL_Quit();
        }

        //Initialize quit bool
        quit = false;


    }

    void handle(){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            eventList.push_back(event); // This adds the events to the eventList
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
                TTF_Quit();
                SDL_Quit();
                quit = true;
            }
            if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED){
                width = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w;
                height = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->h;

            }

            //Update Mouse State
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
            for (std::vector<SDL_Event>::const_iterator i = eventList.begin(); i != eventList.end(); ++i){
                if (i->type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                    if (i->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w){
                        std::cout << "w key pressed\n";
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    std::vector<SDL_Event> get(){
        return eventList;
    }

    void flush_events(){
        eventList.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is your `get()` function; it returns a copy of a vector. Then you try to iterate over it, but your begin and end iterators are from different vectors, because get was called twice. I'm surprised it didn't crash or hang, actually. If you want a copy, store it in some variable and iterate over that; if you don't, make `get` return a reference, e.g. `std::vector<SDL_Event> &get() { return eventList; }`.

Comment: As for not clearing event array - it'll grow larger and larger, consuming more and more memory and taking more iterations to check. Furthermore, does it even make sense? If you check for event, you usually aren't interested in keypress happened 10 minutes ago, do you? But of course if you really want to you can clear only older events after several frames, it doesn't have to be just one frame (or full clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way is to have some functions that are called for each event, whether that be mouse movement, mouse clicks, window resizes ect, and those should be handled in your main event loop by calling `while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))` then have some if statements for each event and call the corresponding functions when those if statements are reached. SDL does this because you may have more then 1 event at the same time, ie, moving the mouse while pressing 'w' like any fps game. You can (im guessing by your example) just appending them to a vector within that event polling loop but then that defeats the purpose of having it loop through the events as youll just have to end up doing that to your vector anyway. You should just make some API variables that are set to some value when a specific event occurs, for example, instead of having functions, just have static variables such as `static unsigned int mousePosition[2]` and set `[0]` to the x mouse position an `[1]` to the y mouse position and then use that somewhere in the program when you need the mouse coordinates, or just even `static SDL_Point mousePosition = {x, y}` in that example.

Eg: (with a singleton class)

```
#pragma once

#ifndef EVENTS_H
#define EVENTS_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>




class Events    ///Singleton
{
public:
    Events(const Events&) = delete;
    Events(Events&&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(const Events&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(Events&&) = delete;




    static const bool& Display_Changed_Size();


    ///Mouse
    static const SDL_Point& Mouse_Pos();

    static const bool& Scrolled_Down();
    static const bool& Scrolled_Up();



    ///Keyboard
    static const std::string& Get_Text_Input();
    static const bool& Pasted_Text();
    static const bool& Copied_Text();

    static const bool& Backspace();



private:
    Events();


    static Events& Get_Instance();


    ///Allow Main to access private members. Works well, one instance, only called once for those functions too. in Main
    friend class Main;

    ///For event handling
    static void Event_Loop();


    ///For event handling
    static void Reset_Events();


    ///For quitting, used main only
    static const bool& Quit_Application();



    ///For Event_Loop()
    int eventLoopCounter = 0;   ///To ensure Event_Loop() doesn't get used twice in the same loop
    SDL_Event event;




    bool m_quit = false;

    bool m_Display_Changed_Size = false;



    ///Mouse
    SDL_Point m_Mouse_Pos = {0,0};
    bool m_Scrolled_Up = false;
    bool m_Scrolled_Down = false;



    ///Keyboard
    std::string m_Text_Input = "";
    bool m_Copied_Text = false;
    bool m_Pasted_Text = false;
    bool m_Backspace = false;



};



#endif // EVENTS_H
```

and the `.cpp`

```
#include "events.h"


Events::Events()
{
    std::cout << "Events constructor called\n";
}


Events& Events::Get_Instance()
{
    static Events instance;
    return instance;
}




void Events::Event_Loop()
{

    if (Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter == 0)
    {

        Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter += 1;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&Get_Instance().event) != 0)
        {
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_quit = true;
                break;
            }


            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT){
                if(Get_Instance().event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {
                    Get_Instance().m_Display_Changed_Size = true;
                }
            }





            ///Mouse
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_Mouse_Pos = {Get_Instance().event.motion.x, Get_Instance().event.motion.y};
            }


            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_MOUSEWHEEL){

                if (Get_Instance().event.wheel.y > 0){  ///Scrolling up here
                    Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Up = true;
                }
                if (Get_Instance().event.wheel.y < 0){  ///Scrolling down here
                    Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Down = true;
                }
            }


            ///Keyboard
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_Text_Input = Get_Instance().event.text.text;
                break;  ///Break here for multiple key presses registered at once
            }

            ///Keydown
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {


                ///Handle copy
                if( Get_Instance().event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c && SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL )
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_Copied_Text = true;
                }
                ///Handle paste
                if( Get_Instance().event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_v && SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL )
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_Pasted_Text = true;
                }


                if (Get_Instance().event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE)
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_Backspace = true;
                }

            }



        }

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Called Events::Event_Loop(); more than once\n";
    }

}



void Events::Reset_Events()
{
    Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter = 0;

    Get_Instance().m_quit = false;

    Get_Instance().m_Display_Changed_Size = false;


    ///Mouse
    Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Down = false;
    Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Up = false;




    ///Keyboard
    Get_Instance().m_Text_Input = "";
    Get_Instance().m_Pasted_Text = false;
    Get_Instance().m_Copied_Text = false;

    Get_Instance().m_Backspace = false;


}


const bool& Events::Quit_Application()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_quit;
}

const bool& Events::Display_Changed_Size()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Display_Changed_Size;
}





///Mouse
const SDL_Point& Events::Mouse_Pos()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Mouse_Pos;
}


const bool& Events::Scrolled_Down()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Down;
}

const bool& Events::Scrolled_Up()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Scrolled_Up;
}







///Keyboard
const std::string& Events::Get_Text_Input()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Text_Input;
}


const bool& Events::Pasted_Text()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Pasted_Text;
}
const bool& Events::Copied_Text()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Copied_Text;
}

const bool& Events::Backspace()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Backspace;
}
```

I understand its alot of code but this type of implementation is what I use when I use SDL2, its not prone to any errors as its just a singleton, noone can instantiate and hence modify members. I would modify the line of `friend class Main` since its there so my main loop class can call the private functions. Even something like `friend int main(int argc, char* argv[]);` so the `int main()` can call it or something as such. In order to use it, just include the header "events.h" in anywhere you need events to be called

**Usage in mainloop, assuming Mainloop is a function or class and is a friend of `Events`, just change the existing friend code in the header**

Mainloop:

```
Events::Event_Loop();
.. Code
Events::Reset_Events();
```

In other files that need events:

```
if ( SDL_PointInRect( &Events::Mouse_Pos(), &rct) ) {} //example
```

Comment: Wall o' Text! >.< Please break it up with some whitespace and code snippets.

Comment: I want access to the events themselves so I could easily check for any events. I make a copy of the event queue because SDL removes the events after the first loop of checking for the events. My program aims to rectify this by copying the required events into a vector so they can be used anywhere in the program until the next frame were all the evnts are reset

Comment: Yeah I get that, if you make static variables for each event and set them to the correct value as the events occur, you can just reference the value of the variable anywhere. Ill update my answer for an example

Comment: This is imo the most efficient way to handle the events, not the cleanest or most elegant or most structured, of course you can modify that. The method you have will work but any time you want to check for an event you need to loop through the vector which after the program gets larger it will be an exponentially slow method for handling events

Comment: Could you provide a code example on how to use the singleton class above.

Comment: Yeah, its pretty easy. Aside from in `Main`, where you would call `Get_Instance().Event_Handling()` and the reset event function, anywhere you need to use it you just include `events.h` and then call, `Events::Mouse_Pos();` and it returns a const reference to it which you can use to either make a new variable out of or just pass it into an SDL function without allocating new memory for a new variable. Just an example

Comment: @Dextron I put an example in the answer above